# Android Shared Preferences max size and Auto Login approach

Tags: android

I come with 2 questions:

First one is about Shared Preferences. I have a login page that requests data from the server everytime I do the login. I was wondering if I can store that data (most of them are URL's and Name) in Shared Preferences to load them faster if nothing changed.

I have searched about Shared Preferences and I found that it basically is an XML file stored in local path so I don't think there is a problem.

My second problem that I have searched and didn't find anything: Is there a way to hide the Activity while doing an auto login? I already implemented the auto login but I need to hide the activity and pass through the next one without the user interacting with the login one.

Comment: For 2nd problem its simple you would have a flag in shared preferences for isLoggedIn `true` or `false`. If user is Logged in then start the MainActivity before LoginActivity,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the second question you can have the following flow: Launch Main Activity and check if the user is logged in. If it is, then there's nothing to do. Else, execute `finish()` method on actual Activity and call Login Activity. In latter you make the logic and then execute `finish()` and call Main Activity again.

Comment: How do I stop my activity from running after changing to my login activity ?

Comment: Simply calling `finish()` after launching the Login Activity. A little example that should be on the Main Activity: `if (userIsNotLoggedIn()) {
   Intent i = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
   startActivity(i);
   finish();
  }`

Comment: Doesn't working, some of my assyncTask that I start from mainActivity still running after switching to loginActivity             Intent intent = new Intent(musicPlayer.this, LoginActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            finish();
            startActivity(intent);

Comment: Hmmm, you should bring those tasks to the foreground then

Answer (score 1):

for auto login just take one flag in preference and set it to true when you are logged In than check in your splash activity if flag is true then go to next activity else go to login activity.